df.replace() unable to replace nan strings in the data frame
The data reads information from a txt file, and it includes some nan values. I try to replace all nan with zero using data.replace('nan', 0). But the nan values in the series cannot be found.
file = 'RAO.txt'
data = pd.read_csv(file, sep="\t", header=None, skiprows=1)
data = data.drop(data.columns[-1], axis=1)
print(data)
print(type(data.iloc[0, 2]))
data.replace('nan', 0, inplace=True)
print(data)

The output of above code is

As shown, nan still exist in data after running the code. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks!

If Nan is actually present, it seems that there is too much data and the 'True' value is not seen.
You can check how many Nan there are with print(data.isnull().sum())

1. Modify the original object: inplace:
By default, fillna(), ffill(), and bfill() return a new object without modifying the original. Setting the inplace argument to True modifies the original object.
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

2. Replace nan string with a value:
df.replace('nan', 0, inplace=True)

Full example:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'colA':[0.6, "nan", "0.04+0.0j", np.nan],
                   'colB':[np.nan, "0.04+0.0j", 6, "nan"]})

df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df.replace('nan', 0, inplace=True)

Original data frame:



colA
colB




0.6
nan


nan
0.04+0.0j


0.04+0.0j
6


nan
nan



Data frame after fillna and replace:



colA
colB




0.6
0


0
0.04+0.0j


0.04+0.0j
6


0
0



